# Rails giving rank to student from admin dashboard

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I am building online admission system using ruby on rails. I want to calculate and store the ranks in table containing user_id and rank  after the registration process is over using single click of a button from admin dashboard. How to do that ? should I put that  in a function in admin model using ActiveRecord::Base.connect() and then using execute() ?? 
I know the sql query should be

```
INSERT into ranks
   (user_id, rank)
    SELECT user_id,
(select count(*)+1 from academics B where A.hs_mks_per < B.hs_mks_per ) AS Rank
 from academics A
order by hs_mks_per desc ;
```

I am  particularly new at programming with rails please help me.

Comment: please clear, what you want to ask?

Answer (score 0):

**Associations**

You'll want to look at [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

As Rails runs on a [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) system - basically meaning that if you create various `ActiveRecod` associations, it will allow you to call *associative* data through "parent" objects

Here's an example:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :academics
    has_one :rank
end

#app/models/academic.rb
Class Academic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/rank.rb
Class Rank < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end
```

If this is the case, it will allow you to do this:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def rank
       user = User.find params[:id]
       @rank = user.rank
    end
end
```

--

**Implementation**

If you want to implement this into your own system, I would recommend setting the data you need for `rank` in your controller, and saving to your model directly:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def save_rank
        user = User.find params[:id]
        rank = ... #-> your calculation here

        user.rank.create(rank: rank)
    end
end
```

Comment: I have done already as you have said problem is with rank I cant create rank with single users data alone it is relative that is I have to calculate rank relative to other users marks.

Comment: Your question asked about how to save the data, not how to calculate your rank. Can you update your question with references to how you need to calculate the ranks?